# Comments only showing subject, no comment

Tags: 7, comments

Using Drupal 7 with a custom made theme, the comments are only showing Subjects, and ignoring the comment body.

In my comment.tpl.php file I have:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php print $picture ?>

<?php if ($new): ?>
<span class="new"><?php print $new ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title ?></h3>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

<div class="submitted">
<?php //print $permalink; ?>
<?php print $submitted; ?>
</div>

<div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['links']);
  print render($content);

?>
<?php if ($signature): ?>
<div class="user-signature clearfix">
  <?php print $signature ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas on how to get the comment to show?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and it was pretty obviously now that I found it. In content type --> Edit --> Comment Display --> The Comment field was hidden! DUH!! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is not different from what used from the Bartik theme for its comment template file.

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

<!-- Omissis -->

<?php if ($new): ?>
  <span class="new"><?php print $new; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<h3<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

<div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
  <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>
  <?php if ($signature): ?>
  <div class="user-signature clearfix">
    <?php print $signature; ?>
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!-- /.content —>
```

I would check if the applied CSS styles are not making the comment body invisible, or if there is a module that, because a bug or not, is not removing the body from comments.
The last point is easy to check: If you change the theme, and the comments still show only the title, then it's not a problem with the theme being used.

Comment: I dont see anything in CSS that would hide the comments section. Could the problem be part of my page.tpl.php file:

Comment: I also changed the Theme to Bartik and it still only showed the Comment Subject, without the comment.

Comment: In that case, it's not a problem with the theme, if you didn't alter the Bartik theme. In that case, I would check if there is a module that is causing the problem, but disabling each third-party module you installed.

Comment: I found the solution and it was pretty obviously now that I found it. 

In content type --> Edit --> Comment Display --> The Comment field was hidden!

DUH!! :)

Comment: @clk1981 When you can, add that as answer, and accept it.